# SharePoint Master Page and Pages/Site Pages?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

I've created a master page and assigned it to the site collection using:
Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Master page

My problem is that this master page only effects pages in the "Pages" library and not the "Site Pages" library.

Is this typical behavior? 
How do I change the master page for "Site Pages"?
Can I set a master page that will affect both?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two kind of master pages in SharePoint

1. **Site Master Pages**: used by all publishing pages – and only by
   publishing pages
2. **System Master Pages**: used by everything else including forms and
   view pages

You cannot change the default behavior – but you can use SharePoint Designer to change the master page assignment for individual pages if required.

If you open a page in SharePoint Designer you can see a MasterPageFile setting which can be modified:

- “~masterurl/default.master”: the page will use the system master page
- “~masterurl/custom.master”: the page will use the site master page

Comment: Thanks DOM, very informative.
How do I change the system master page?